# When I add rows to my Excel table certain columns automatically populate with =[@TOTAL] - how do I stop this from happening?

Tags: excel-formula

When I add rows to my Excel table certain columns automatically populate with =[@TOTAL] - how do I stop this from happening?

I have been deleting these each time but I would rather stop this from happening. The other worksheets are not doing this.

Comment: May be you need to check the `AutoCorrect Options` --> `File`-->`Options`-->`Proofing`-->`AutoCorrect Options`-->`AutoFormat As You Type`-->`Uncheck`.

Comment: Also this question suits here: **[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel?tab=Newest)**

Comment: Thanks for your message. If that was the issue, this would be happening on all worksheets I would think. It is only happening on one worksheet which is almost identical to another which does not have the problem. I will give it a try regardless.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.